# Delete records from Google Datastore using simple GQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I have a Google DataStore that I inherited 
and this Datastore has about 9M records.
I'd like to remove all old records (say everything that is older than 1 month old).
Generally speaking, when I use google cloud console Datastore->query by kind, I'm able to put SQL like statements:

```
select * from table limit 5
```

however when I try using the "query by gql" to do something like delete rows:

```
delete from table where date<"2019-01-01"
```

It doesn't work- I get the error: "GQL Query error: Encountered "delete" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting: "select" ...
"

Is there a simple way to run delete on all old records?

Comment: The easy way would be to write a script checking all conditions and then deleting.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use GQL to delete. If you want to delete you should use one of the client [libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#deleting_an_entity).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to write a script and run it whenever you need.

Code (Python 2.7):

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from datetime import date

kind = ModelX  #kind whose entries you want to delete
check = date(2019,1,1)   # Date to be used to check records 

# GQL Query to fetch keys of all older records
all_keys = kind.gql("WHERE date <= :1",check).fetch(keys_only = True)

# Deleting all entries at once
ndb.delete_multi(all_keys)
```

Hope this answers your question!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can not use GQL to delete entities.

You can delete entities manually using UI delete button or using datastore.delete() method to delete entities